# PHP - Object converted to Array, now need a Value

Tags: php

I've managed to confuse myself here, I have an object that I've converted to an array and now want to get the value of:

```
echo var_dump((array)$obj['country_id']);
```

Gives an output of:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "GB" }
```

How do I simply get "GB"?

Comment: Try this: $result[0];

Comment: No need for `echo` before `var_dump()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, `$res = (array)$arr['country_id']; echo $res[0];` worked perfectly

Comment: `echo $obj['country_id'][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$result = (array)$arr['country_id'];
echo $result[0];
```